# C - Segmentation fault trying to put the top of a Stack into a Char array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault in my code and am unable to explain why. I am writing a program that takes a infix expression and converts to postfix using a stuct stack.

Heres my main and declaration of methods as well as declaration of of my stack:

```
#define LINELN 72
#define STACKSZ 25 
#define NEWLN '\n' 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct stack {
char data[STACKSZ];
int top;
} stack;

void initstk(stack *s1);
int emptystk(stack s1);
char peek(stack s);
int getline(char infix[]);
void push(char item, stack *s);
char pop(stack *s);
int preced(char x);
void processinfix(char infix[], int l, char postifx[]);
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char infix[LINELN];
char postfix[LINELN];

processinfix(infix,getline(infix),postfix);

 exit(0);
}
```

My methods that I have tested and that are working are the basic stack manipulation methods:

```
//makes top of stack -1
void initstk(stack *s1) {

s1->top=-1;
}

//returns 1 if stack is empty, 0 otherwise
int emptystk(stack s) {


if(s.top == -1){
return one;
}
else{
    return 0;

}
}
 //peeks at top of the stack
char peek(stack s) {
return s.data[s.top];
}
//pushes value to top of stack 
void push(char item, stack *s) {
   s->top = s->top +1;
   s->data[s->top] = item;

}
//pops off the top of stack and returns it
char pop(stack *s) {

char x;
x = s -> data[s->top];
s-> top =s->top-1;
return x;
}
//gives character a precedence number according to what it is
int preced(char x) {

switch (x) {
    case '(':
    case ')':
        return 3;
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
        return 2;
    case '+':        case '-':
        return 1;
  }
    return 0;
}
```

I have a function getLine() that takes in user input that would be expression, for example: A+B, and stores it in infix[]

```
int getline(char infix[]){

    char c;
    int i=0;
    printf("Type in your expression");
    while((c = getchar()) !=NEWLN && i <= LINELN && c != ' ' ){
    infix[i]=c;
    i++;
}
return i;   


}
```

My next function is what sorts the infix expression and puts it into postfix[]

```
   void processinfix(char infix[], int inlen, char postfix[])
  {
    stack s1;
    initstk(&s1);
    printf("%d characters are in infix\n", inlen);
    int i =0;       
    int k=0;

            // while "i" isnt bigger then the number of elements in infix
    while( i<sizeof(infix)){

           /* if infix[i] is a letter send it to post fix right away, 
             increment inlen down one because infix is now smaller by 1 */

if (('a'<=  infix[i]&& infix[i] <= 'z') ||( 'A' <= infix[i]&& infix[i] 
     <='Z')){

        printf("%c is a letter, sending to postfix\n", infix[i]);
        postfix[k] = infix[i];
        inlen--;
        printf("infix has shrinked by 1\n");
        k++;


}
 /* else if infix[i] has a higher precedence then whats on top of stack 
  push infix[i] on to stack and increment inlen down 1 */
  else if(preced(infix[i])>preced( s1.data[s1.top])){

       push(infix[i],&s1);
       inlen--;
       printf("infix has shrinked by 1\n");
       printf("%c is top of stack\n", s1.data[s1.top]);

} 

   /* else if infix[i] is lower or equal to whats on top of stack. put 
   top of  stack into postfix[] until infix[i] is higher precedene then 
    top of stack. then put it on top of stack and decrease */

else if(preced(infix[i]) <= preced(s1.data[s1.top])){

       printf("%c is  higher or equal  then %c\n", s1.data[s1.top], 
       infix[i]);

    while (preced(infix[i])<=preced(s1.data[s1.top])){
        postfix[k] = s1.data[s1.top];
        printf("%c is put into postfix expression\n", s1.data[s1.top]);
        pop(&s1);
        k++;

 }

    push(infix[i], &s1);
    inlen--;
    printf("%c is now the top\n", s1.data[s1.top]);

 }

// if nothing is left in infix pop stack until s1.top = -1 

if(inlen==0){
     printf("nothing left in infix\n");
     while (s1.top!= -1){
     printf("sendin %c to postfix\n", s1.data[s1.top]);
     postfix[k]=s1.data[s1.top]
     pop(&s1);
     k++;
}

break;
}

i++;
}

// print postfix
int x=0;
while(x<= sizeof(postfix)){
printf("%s",postfix[x]);
x++;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

The output that I am getting is

```
Type in your expressionA+B
3 characters are in infix
A is a letter, sending to postfix
infix has shrinked by 1
infix has shrinked by 1
+ is top of stack
B is a letter, sending to postfix
infix has shrinked by 1
nothing left in infix
sending + to postfix
Segmentation fault
```

so everything is running fine until it runs into

```
if(inlen==0){
    printf("nothing left in infix\n");
    while (s1.top!= -1){
    printf("sendin %c to postfix\n", s1.data[s1.top]);
    THIS LINE -> postfix[k]=s1.data[s1.top]<-THIS LINE
    pop(&s1);
    k++;
}
```

Postfix[k] = s1.data[s1.top]; works earliar in the while loops but just not here. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: Perhaps compile with debugging and look at the stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: And also, for us to be able to help you, you need to show us the actual code. What you have shown here doesn't compile, so you can't have been running it. But a suggestion is to compile with warnings enabled, and pay attention to what your compiler tells you!

Comment: @thomasPadron-mccarthy It compiles and runs using g++ and in the linux terminal? It would run for you

Comment: `g++` is a C++ compiler, not C.

Comment: @Lagging: Errors on "return one" and for a missing semicolon.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], focus on *minimal*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. G++ also will compile C. Source: https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/compiling_C_programs.html

Comment: That page is utterly wrong with it's premise "*but since C is directly compatible with C++*. It is not. In both ways.

Comment: @Lagging: g++ will compile C++. That source claims that "C is directly compatible with C++", and that is not true, whatever they mean by "directly compatible". C and C++ are different languages. It doesn't seem to be the cause of your problems in this case, but it can cause you all sorts of grief if you believe them. Again: Compile with warnings enabled, and pay attention to what your compiler tells you!

Comment: This is a live test of your code: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/ZSzd8TakLlQFeQ9A,  it seems there is an array out-of-bounds read at line 120.   I combined your code into one file, so the line # might be off a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing some errors, so the code compiles, you will get several warnings from the compiler. One of them is this:

```
foo.c:183:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s",postfix[x]);
                 ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~
                 %d
```

You are using the wrong format specifier. `postfix[x]` is a character (which is converted to integer in this case, thus the warning about "int"), not a string. You should use `"%c"` and not `"%s"`.

After this change, the program no longer crashes when I run it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Unfortunately my code hits the segmentation fault before that line is executed. So it is still giving me the error of segmentation fault.

Comment: The program doesn't crash for me. But have you checked the other warnings? About sizeof?

Comment: Thomas pador-mccarthy Yes I am trying a new condtion to loop through infix[]